# Why HashMap insert new Node on index (n - 1) & hash?

Tags: java, hash, collections, hashmap, hashcode

Why HashMap insert new Node on the index:
`tab[(n - 1) & hash]`

Where `hash = key.hashCode() ^ key.hashCode() >>> 16`
And `n = tab.length` of array of `Node<K,V>`.

Why HashMap not put the Node just like that: `tab[hash]` ? Is it just another hashing function, like multiplication by 31 in most of `hashCode()` methods ?
Thanks in advance for explanation!

Comment: Hint: `n` will be a power of two...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because `hash` may be out of range.

The "canonical solution" is to take the (positive) modulo of the hash with the length of the array, this code uses the fact that the array has a power-of-two length to replace an expensive modulo by a variable (modulo a constant is optimized pretty well) with a cheap bitwise AND.

Comment: Would like to learn more about this statement, if you have time, "array has a power-of-two length to replace an expensive modulo by a variable (modulo a constant is optimized pretty well) with a cheap bitwise AND." Unable to understand how array has power of 2 making it optimized. If you refer some links or explain. @aniket-thakur

Comment: @Tarun the condition for replacing `x % n` with `x & (n - 1)` is that `n` must be a power of two. `n` is the length of the array in this case. The array having a power of 2 length does not *itself* optimize anything, but it enables using that trick.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. If n is power of 2, n-1 will be of the format 0111....1 which would make x & (n-1) equivalent to x%n.

Answer (score 20):

A good description by harold but I feel it is inadequate without an example. So heres one -

Whenever a new Hasmap is created the array size of internal Node[] table is always power of 2 and following method guarantees it -

```
static final int tableSizeFor(int cap) {
    int n = cap - 1;
    n |= n >>> 1;
    n |= n >>> 2;
    n |= n >>> 4;
    n |= n >>> 8;
    n |= n >>> 16;
    return (n < 0) ? 1 : (n >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) ? MAXIMUM_CAPACITY : n + 1;
}
```

So lets say you provide initial capacity as 5

```
cap = 5
n = cap - 1 =  4 = 0 1 0 0
n |= n >>> 1;    0 1 0 0 | 0 0 1 0 = 0 1 1 0 = 6
n |= n >>> 2;    0 0 1 1 | 0 1 1 0 = 0 1 1 1 = 7
n |= n >>> 4;    0 0 0 0 | 0 1 1 1 = 0 1 1 1 = 7
n |= n >>> 8;    0 0 0 0 | 0 1 1 1 = 0 1 1 1 = 7
n |= n >>> 16;   0 0 0 0 | 0 1 1 1 = 0 1 1 1 = 7
return n + 1     7 + 1 = 8
```

So table size is 8 = 2^3

Now possible index values you can put your element in map are 0-7 since table size is 8. Now lets look at put method. It looks for bucket index as follows -

```
Node<K,V> p =  tab[i = (n - 1) & hash];
```

where n is the array size. So n = 8. It is same as saying

```
Node<K,V> p =  tab[i = hash % n];
```

So all we need to see now is how

```
hash % n == (n - 1) & hash
```

Lets again take an example. Lets say hash of a value is 10.

```
hash = 10
hash % n = 10 % 8 = 2
(n - 1) & hash = 7 & 10 = 0 1 1 1 & 1 0 1 0 = 0 0 1 0 = 2
```

Hope this helps. [More details](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2015/02/understanding-how-hashmap-and-hashset.html)

PS: Above link goes to my blog that has a more details example explanation on this.

Comment: Clear answer. Thank you.

Comment: nice blog. I am reading all the post :D